# Alternatives to comparing object property using if...else

Tags: javascript

I hope I make my question clear. 
I have a few objects which I have created with a property called address. For example, Obj1 has address 0x0000, Obj2 has address 0x0004 and so on. 
There is a list of random input addresses which I need to process. Once the input address is one of the object address (if addr=0x0000||addr=0x0004....), then a function will be automatically loaded. 
Currently, I am comparing it by a list of Object addresses, which I think is a waste of iteration. Is there any way, I can access it by index? For example, once I enter an input address of 0x0004, a function will be run directly.

edit : Thanks for all your answers :) I have a clearer idea now

Comment: Maybe you want to look at `case`

Comment: Perhaps a dictionary/object? `{ '0x000': function () { .. }, .. }[addr]()`?

Comment: Would be more clear if you provide some example code.

Answer (score 3):

You got 2 choices:

Use switch to define all functions:

```
switch (input){
case '0x0000': function(input){}; break;
case ...
}
```

Use a predefined map:

```
var functionMappings = { 
  '0x0000': function_1,
  '0x0001': function_2,
};

if(functionMappings[input]) {
  functionMappings[input](input);
}
```

I would prefer the second example, because it can be created dynamically in the runtime.

**Update**:
You can create your `functionMappings` dynamicaly like this:

```
var functionMappings = {// create first entries, or defualt functions
  '0x0001': function_1,
  '0x0002': function_2
};

if(condition_x) {  // add new or overwrite existing functions
   functionMappings[0x0005] = function_5;
}
```

Because this is an map, you can even overwrite default function definitions, if you need.

Comment: Yes, I ment to assign an function to a dictionary key (I forgot to remove bracets :) )

Comment: You might need `'0x0000': function_1` since  `0x0000 !== '0x0000'`.

Comment: Good point, but  instead of  hex numbers, we should go with either decimal or string names, they would be cleaner to read.

Comment: @Beri  I like your second example, i think it is what i'm looking for. Is it possible to dynamically create the 'predefined map' as well?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate once and put all addresses as keys to an object:

```
var addresses = {};
for(var i=0;i<objList.length;i++){
    addresses[objList[i].addr] = {};
    addresses[objList[i].addr].fn = correspondingFunction

    // you can even attach the corresponding object to it
    // addresses[objList[i].addr].obj = addresses[objList[i].addr];
}
```

*I use a loop for the example but you can do it any way that suits you*

Then you have a list of your objects keyed by their address, and you can fetch them by it:

```
function getAddrFunction(addr){
    if(addresses[addr] !== undefined){
        return addresses[addr].fn;
    }
    return null;
}
```